# Is it possible to put different colors for text in multiple line textbox

Tags: asp.net, fonts, textbox, multiline

I have one text box with multiple line option. Now i want type the words inside the text box with different font-size and different colors. Is it possible?

Comment: It's not possible with a TextBox. You have to use a RichTextBox for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possble.. you can use a WYSWYG editor, like  http://nicedit.com/